# How to add a text input to alert in react native

Tags: react-native

Can someone help with adding a text input to an alert in react native. Is it possible? I searched and found results that deals with multiple line text input which is not the case with me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal) instead of alert.

Comment: As I know it is not possible for case of system alerts. You can design you own pop-up components. I suggest [react-native-popup-dialog](https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-popup-dialog)

Comment: I tried to solve this by using react-native-popover. It worked well and was simple to use as well.Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 22):

This is possible. I believe this was only available initially for AlertIOS however it seems to have been intergrated to React Native Alert.

Edit: Although its added to Alert it does not seem to work for Android

Use

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native'; 

onButtonPress = () => {
    Alert.prompt(
      "Enter password",
      "Enter your password to claim your $1.5B in lottery winnings",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        {
          text: "OK",
          onPress: password => console.log("OK Pressed, password: " + password)
        }
      ],
      "secure-text"
    );
  };
}
```

More details: https://reactnative.dev/docs/alertios

Comment: currently iOS only

Answer (score 6):

Use `react-native-dialog` it works across platform and is simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you could add a text input to the Alert component according to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert), You will need to create a custom component by yourself in order to achieve that, example: use customise modal or use [react-native-simple-dialogs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-dialogs)

Answer (score -1):

No way
Just use custom modal or third party library to achieve this...

Answer (score -1):

If you think for a moment you will find that an alert and a modal are both a kind of pop-up components. And that leads you to create your own pop-up component instead of using ready-made if you don't have it.

```js
return (
  <Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={true}
    onBackdropPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
    visible={props.modalVisible}
    onRequestClose={ResetValues}>
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#4D4D4D',
        width: (windowWidth * 100) / 100,
        height: (windowHeight * 100) / 100,
      }}>
      
     !!!!!!!!! your elements here like text,input,buttons and etc....!!!!!

    </View>
  </Modal>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a spoiler using a custom Modal:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import { View, TextInput, Modal, GestureResponderEvent } from 'react-native';
import { BoldText, IOSButton } from '..';
import { colors } from '../../constants';

import { customModalStyles, defaultStyles } from '../../styles';

interface Props {
  modalVisible: boolean;
  // onRequestClose,
  textOne: string;
  buttonOneTitle: string;
  onPressOne: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void;
  value: string,
  onChangeText: (text: string) => void;,
  placeholder: string
}

const InputModal: FC<Props> = ({
  modalVisible,
  // onRequestClose,
  textOne,
  buttonOneTitle,
  onPressOne,
  value,
  onChangeText,
  placeholder
}) => {

  return (
    <Modal
      animationType="fade"
      transparent={true}
      visible={modalVisible}
    // onRequestClose={onRequestClose}
    >
      <View style={customModalStyles.centeredView}>
        <View style={customModalStyles.modalView}>
          <BoldText
            style={customModalStyles.textSize}>{textOne}
          </BoldText>

          <TextInput
            secureTextEntry
            autoCapitalize="none"
            style={[
              defaultStyles.inputStyle,
              defaultStyles.textInputShadow,
            ]}
            value={value}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            placeholderTextColor={colors.placeHolder}
          />
          <IOSButton title={buttonOneTitle}
            onPress={onPressOne}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default InputModal;
```

And the styles:

```js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { colors } from '../constants';
import styleConstants from './styleConstants';

const customModalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  modalView: {
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: styleConstants.width < 1000 ? 320 : 400,
    height: styleConstants.height < 1000 ? 320 : 400,
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
    borderRadius: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingTop: 10,
    shadowColor: colors.secondary,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 4,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.55,
    shadowRadius: 8,
    elevation: 20,
  },
  textSize: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: styleConstants.fontSizeSM,
  },
});

export default customModalStyles;
```

Then one may use it like this:

```js
{modalVisible && (
        <InputModal
          modalVisible={modalVisible}
          textOne={`...`}
          buttonOneTitle="..."
          onPressOne={async () => {
            setModalVisible(false);
            validatePasswordEtc()
          }}
          placeholder="..."
          value={password}
          onChangeText={handleChangePassword}
        />
      )}
```