# Alert prompt (Alert with input value update) not working in android using react-native (Working in iOS)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, alert

I am using Alert.prompt to update a text field in the react-native app. But it not opening the alert in the android app.

In iOS app alert with input box update working fine.

```
onEditText = (field) => {
  Alert.prompt('Change ' + field + ':', this.props[field], (value) =>
   this.props.setProfileField(field, value),
 );
}
```

Comment: Any console message or warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a text input to alert in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55115365/how-to-add-a-text-input-to-alert-in-react-native)

Comment: You could also use something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialog-input

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli I not received any logs

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [React Native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert#prompt-ios), `Alert.prompt` only works for IOS. If you seek and Android alternative you can check this:

https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-prompt-android

This is a native alternative, for JS alternatives there would be:

https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-dialog

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-prompt-crossplatform